# Solr apply filters on stored data

Tags: java, lucene, solr

Is it possible to apply filters to stored data like we can apply filter when indexing. For example I use KeepWordFilter on a filed during indexing. But I don't want filtered data to be  even stored.

```
    <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField"                           
        positionIncrementGap="100">                                         
        <analyzer type="index">                                             
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />           
            <!--                                                            
                in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time <filter
                class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt"
                ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>                          
            -->                                                             
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true"        
                words="stopwords.txt" />
   ....
```

Is there an analyser type stored? If not what are the alternatives?

Answer (score 2):

There is no analyzer for stored. The values are stored as is without any modifications.
You would need to add the handling before the data is fed to Solr, probably at the client side.

Comment: In that case when retrieving data is it possible to get what is there in index? I find that when querying data what is returned is the stored data.

Comment: Nope. Its not possible to get back the indexed data with the response. You can use tools like luke to check the indexed data.

Comment: Is Luke something I can use in a production setup?

Comment: Luke is a tool which will help you analyze your index. http://www.getopt.org/luke/ . It loads the index and help to look at the indexed data and much more. you can use it for production setup as well. There is also a web interface for luke through solr admin http://wiki.apache.org/solr/LukeRequestHandler. However, am not sure if it provides the exact same functionality as the tool.